# A distinct off-topic reason for questions asking for code review or development

Tags: discussion, review-queues, flags, scope

While doing review tasks, I often have to somehow address questions where someone asks us to solve some task for him/her or to review/refactor a long piece of code. While such questions are definitely off-topic, our off-topic reason menu doesn't provide any direct and clear choice for that case. Well.. Sometimes there exists another reason that may be applied (an unclear question or no attempt to investigate some buggy code or anything else). Still, what should I do if there is no code to debug at all and the task is rather clear but very particular and not of interest for the community?

I think it would be good to have a distinct off-topic menu reason for that situation, say "Asking for code development/review.. "

Comment: My gut just says that if all they want is a general review of their code, then their question is too broad for Stack Overflow, which is for actual specific programming questions. So the too broad close reason should be plenty good for this situation, usually accompanied by a comment suggesting that the user investigate if the Code Review Stack Exchange would be appropriate for their needs .

Comment: Looks reasonable although not so obvious .. Thanks!

Comment: "but very particular and not of interest for the community" - ah, the old [too localised close reason](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/184154/268911).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Too broad" works for questions which ask us for tips on how to improve their code, or for how to refactor their code, because the question is, well, too broad.

As to your point about

> what should I do if there is no code to debug at all and the task is rather clear but very particular and not of interest for the community?

For starters, I'd like to see examples since that can be dealt with on a case-by-case basis (it could be the case that the question is very much on-topic and doesn't merit closure).  However, I'd conjecture a question about an issue with code *sans code* can be closed for not including the actual code and inputs to validate it.